# \centerline messes up the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

If I use `\centerline` to get my chapter title centred, the corresponding entry in the Table of Contents is also being centered. Is there any way around this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{2.3ex plus.2ex}

\\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\rfoot{}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\par\textbf{Name of the Chapter}}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par\medskip}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{\centerline{Title}}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

This is what I'm getting:

---

[image: I'm getting this]

---

This is what I want:

---

[image: I want this]

Comment: Well I have used the titlesec package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code suffers from a number of issues, some of which make it not compilable:

- you use `\hypersetup` which is defined by the `hyperref` package, but you don't load `hyperref`;
- you use `\rfoot` which is defined by the `fancyhdr` package, but you don't load `fancyhdr`;
- you use `\afterpage` which is defined by the `afterpage` package, but you don't load `afterpage`;
- an extra `\` found its way in your code (in front of `\hypersetup`);
- you call `\tableofcontents` and friends in your preamble.

Now, let's address your problem. `\centerline` is used to centre one line of "normal text" and should not be used to format headings. Instead, insert a `\centering` declaration in the first mandatory argument of `\titleformat` in your code, as I did below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{2.3ex plus.2ex}

\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\rfoot{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%\addtocontents{toc}{\par\textbf{Name of the Chapter}}
%\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par\medskip}}

\chapter{Title}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Then, the table of contents produced is

[image]

and the chapter heading produced is centred, as desired:

[image]

Comment: That's a lot of mistakes. Thank you for correcting them :) I'll be more careful the next time.

Comment: Is there any way to begin only the title on a new line and still center the title?

Comment: `\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\\}{0em}{}`